# Getting a sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy exception when trying to set up a spring boot rest test

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit5

I'm currently trying to make a unit test for a small project I'm doing. It's a contact management application which only passes rest apis, also implement login api. I've been reading this guide (https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test/) on how to do it implement unit testing in rest, but I'm getting an exception when I implement the guide in my project. I'd love to get some pointers on how to solve this.

## ContactControllerTest

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ContactController.class)
public class ContactControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private ContactService contactService;

    @Test
    public void createAccount() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/contacts/add";
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setFirst_name("George");
        contact.setLast_name("George2");
        contact.setMobile((long) 12345443);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String inputJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(contact);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(inputJson)).andReturn();
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);
        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(content, "Contact is created successfully");
    }

}
```

## ContactController

```java
@RestController
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    // ADD
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts/add", method = POST)
    public Contact addContact(@RequestBody Contact contact){
        if (!contactService.checkContact(contact)){
           // throw new ContactBadRequestException("Bad contact request");
        }
        return contactService.createContact(contact);
    }
}
```

## ContactService

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>36</groupId>
    <artifactId>36</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

When I try to run the test, I get:
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

```
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
at org.junit.validator.AnnotationsValidator$AnnotatableValidator.validateAnnotatable(AnnotationsValidator.java:65)
at org.junit.validator.AnnotationsValidator$AnnotatableValidator.validateTestClass(AnnotationsValidator.java:54)
at org.junit.validator.AnnotationsValidator.validateTestClass(AnnotationsValidator.java:36)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.applyValidators(ParentRunner.java:134)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.collectInitializationErrors(ParentRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: Have you tried using the latest spring boot version?

Comment: @NatFar I haven't, no. I have to do it under this version.